# Question about scoping data in a multi-level Manipulate construction

Tags: manipulate, scoping

Background: In a module containing an outer / inner manipulate I select the key of data with a dropdownlist in the outer manipulate. Data is read and displayed in the inner manipulate for edit purposes. The outer manipulate contains buttons, one of which is a save button. I want to get the edited data back at that level so that it can be saved.

Consider the following *simplified* example:

```
  Manipulate[
   Column[{j,
   Manipulate[k, {k, 1, 5, 1}],
    Button["Check", Print[k]]
   }],
  {j, 1, 10, 1}]
```

the question then becomes: **"What is the best way to get the variable k scoped to the first / outer manipulate" ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
DynamicModule[{k},
  Manipulate[
   Column[{j,
     Manipulate[k, {k, 1, 5, 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False],
     Button["Check", Print[k]]
   }],
   {j, 1, 10, 1}]
]
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a particular reason why you put the `DynamicModule` on the outside of the outer `Manipulate`?

Comment: @Heike It is not strictly necessary, but in this way, we don't generate a new symbol/variable every time when external `Manipulate` recomputes its body. This is the same logic as when we use external `Module` to create persistent local variables, as for example I discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs/569#569).

Answer (score 5):

Using `LocalizeVariables -> False` as in Leonid's answer is probably the easiest, but the downside is that it makes all controls in the inner `Manipulate` visible to the outer `Manipulate` and beyond. If you have multiple controls in the inner `Manipulate` but you want the outer `Manipulate` to only see some of them to be visible to the outer `Manipulate` you could also do something like

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{k1}, 
  Column[{j, Manipulate[k1 = k, {k, 1, 5, 1}], 
    Button["Check", Print[k1]]}]], {j, 1, 10, 1}]
```

Comment: Heike, I have accepted Leonid's answer because what you refer to as a downside works out rather advantageous in my code.